# jquery fancybox, ie8, Message: 'loading' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

My website has an error in IE 8.0.6001.18702, which is something to do with jquery fancybox 1.3.1.

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/
4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR
3.5.30729)


Message: 'loading' is null or not an object
Line: 36
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: ....../jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js
```

Any ideas? It happens when i try to activate the iframe fancybox. I'm clicking a link in the form of:

```
<a href="" class="iframe fancybox">blah</a>
```

I have a link, but you'd have to sign up to the site to see the error. let me know if you want it

Comment: I think the sign up barrier is going to be too much - why don't you post relevant code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: jsfiddle? that's awesome. aiight i'll post it up tonite. Thanks for that idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to upgrade to the latest version of jquery, 1.4.4 and this sorted out the issue.